# El Capitan, how to choose a specific Java version to run

Tags: macos, java

I'm running El Capitan and `java -version` produces the following:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

I'm having severe slowdown problems with the h2 database console, so I want to see if going back to Java 1.6 has any effect.

I run the Java Preferences application and move 1.6 so it's at the top, but the next time I launch Java Preferences 1.8 is back up there!  Even unchecking 1.8 doesn't persist -- it's rechecked on the next launch.

How does one go about selecting a particular Java version these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just put the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

Comment: Thanks...so what would I do after the test, to get back to normal (1.8)?  The last time I messed with my path variables I had to do a complete system restore so I'm a little anxious :-)

Comment: To get back to 1.8 you could just type `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6\`` from the command line (and remove the `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6\`` from your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  Test completed and useful results obtained.  Many thanks :-)